# jQuery sorting DIVS part II

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7843719/115845) I asked how to sort divs by 2 parameters: name or value, asc or desc.
I wrote all the code with the idead I got and I got all solved but 2 last issues.

This is what I do... To sort the divs, first I concatenate the the value and id and have an array like this:

```
window.sortval = ["76#box1", "71#box122", "125#box4"];
```

(I use window. to make sure its in the global scope)
The first part is the numeric value I want to sort by and the second the ID of the DIV.

ISSUE 1 is that if I run

```
window.sortval.sort(function(a,b){return a - b})
```

it doesn't get sorted.

--
To go on with my experiment I used the browser console and sorted the array by hand. Now I have the second issue. The code I was going to use to do the actual sorting doesn't work:

I have

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sortable" id="box1" rel="76" data-rel="Name One">
        [some inside html including a table and divs]
    </div>
    <div class="sortable" id="box122" rel="71" data-rel="Name Two">
        [some inside html including a table and divs]
    </div>
    <div class="sortable" id="box4" rel="125" data-rel="Name Three">
        [some inside html including a table and divs]
    </div>
</div>
```

and then when I run

```
//get only the id part of each value in the array
var ids = $.map( window.sortname, function(val, i) {
  return val.substring(val.indexOf('#'));
}); 

//sort the DOM
var cont = $('#container');
    $.each(ids, function(i, v) {
    cont.append($(v));
});
```

Nothing happens, not even an error

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the array for something else, this will sort your `.sortable` divs and put them inside `#container`:

```
var sorted = $(".sortable").sort(function(a,b) {
    return $(a).attr("rel") - $(b).attr("rel");
});
var cont = $("#container");
$.each(sorted,function(i,el) {
    cont.append(el);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gx5qw/

Comment: This is great but I don't know why it doesn't work when sorting by name. I switched storing each DIVs name inside the data-rel attribute to title="" attr. So I'm doing return $(a).attr('title') - $(b).attr('title'); and no order changes

Comment: this works for me `var a = $(".sortable").sort(function(a,b) { return a.title - b.title; });`. if you can get the attribute without jQuery, do so.

Comment: of course, if you want to sort strings and not numbers, you can't use `a.title - b.title` but have to do something like what Shawn did.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need..

```
window.sortval = ["76#box1", "71#box122", "125#box4"];


// sort based on the numeric value before the id
window.sortval.sort(function(a,b){
   return a.substring(0, a.indexOf('#')) - b.substring(0, b.indexOf('#'));
}); 

//sort the DOM based on the ordered array by using the ids
var cont = $('#container');
    $.each(window.sortval, function(i, v) {
    cont.append($( v.substring(v.indexOf('#')) ));
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Wdybs/1/

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a rather roundabout way to sort by two keys. You should be able to that using a standard `sort()` with a custom sort function.

Here's one way to do it, sorting first with the `rel` attribute  followed by the `id`:

```
var cnt = $("#container");
var sorted = $(".sortable", cnt).sort(function(a, b) {
    // (optional), cache vars so we don't keep calling $(...)
    var $a = $(a), $b = $(b);
    var a_id = $a.attr("id"), b_id = $b.attr("id");
    var a_rel = $a.attr("rel"), b_rel = $b.attr("rel");

    if (a_rel == b_rel) { // if rel equal, sort by id
        return (a_id > b_id) ? 1 : (a_id < b_id) ? -1 : 0; // String comparison
    } else {
        return a_rel - b_rel; // Numeric comparison
    }
});

// reinsert in sorted order
$.each(sorted, function(i, e) { cnt.append(e); });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8F9Uv/